# Draw order (zIndex) of OpenLayers polygons and points in the same layer

Tags: openlayers-2, vector, layers, style, order

My question is similar but slightly different to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003349/openlayers-vector-features-z-indexing

I have an OpenLayers Vector layer which contains polygons and points from PostGIS. I do not want to create a separate table for each entity. I have a StyleMap set for the layer and have zIndexing set to true. My points are using an external graphic and my polygons just a normal style.

Problem: I cannot get the external graphic to render above the the polygons. If I used a normal point then it does render above the polygons. I believe I've tried all combinations of graphicZIndex and zIndex for the point and polygon layers.

Layer def:

```
        var lyrJamoats = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Jamoats", {
                strategies : [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
                styleMap : Styles.styleJamoat,
                rendererOptions : {
                    zIndexing : true
                },
                protocol: {protocol stuff}
    });
```

Style def:

```
styleJamoat : new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
    "default" : new OpenLayers.Style(null, {
        rules : [new OpenLayers.Rule({
            symbolizer : {
                "Point" : {
                    fillColor : "#ffcc66",
                    strokeColor : "#ff9933",
                    strokeWidth : 2,
                    graphicZIndex : 1000,
                    //zIndex: 99999999,
                    externalGraphic : "./img/jamoat_pin.png",
                    pointRadius : 30
                },
                "Polygon" : {
                    strokeWidth : 2,
                    strokeOpacity : 1,
                    strokeColor : "#FFFFFF",
                    fillColor : "#002776",
                    fillOpacity : 0.75,
                    zIndex: 0
                    //graphicZIndex: 0,
                }
            }
        })]
    }),
```

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to work.  I deleted everything from my PostGIS table then inserted the points before the polygons. I then included zIndex and graphicZIndex properties for the point and polygon style rules. Also added both style rules to the "select" rule as I suspect the hover tool I'm using is interfering with play.

```
styleJamoat : new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
    "default" : new OpenLayers.Style(null, {
        rules : [new OpenLayers.Rule({
            symbolizer : {
                "Point" : {
                    fillColor : "#ffcc66",
                    strokeColor : "#ff9933",
                    strokeWidth : 2,
                    graphicZIndex : 9999999,
                    zIndex: 99999999,
                    externalGraphic : "./img/jamoat_pin.png",
                    pointRadius : 15,
                    fillOpacity : 1,
                },
                "Polygon" : {
                    strokeWidth : 2,
                    strokeOpacity : 1,
                    strokeColor : "#FFFFFF",
                    fillColor : "#002776",
                    fillOpacity : 0.75,
                    zIndex: 1,
                    graphicZIndex: 1,
                }
            }
        })]
    }),
    "select" : new OpenLayers.Style(null, {
        rules : [new OpenLayers.Rule({
            symbolizer : {
                "Point" : {
                    fillColor : "#ffcc66",
                    strokeColor : "#ff9933",
                    strokeWidth : 2,
                    graphicZIndex : 1000,
                    //zIndex: 99999999,
                    externalGraphic : "./img/jamoat_pin_sel.png",
                    pointRadius : 15,
                    fillOpacity : 1,
                },
                "Polygon" : {
                    strokeWidth : 2,
                    strokeOpacity : 1,
                    strokeColor : "#FFFFFF",
                    fillColor : "#12D400",
                    fillOpacity : 0.75
                }
            }
        })]
    })
}),
```